# Wordpress Twenty Twelve - Social icons in navigation menu

Tags: css, wordpress

Im tryin to get social icons in to my navigation menu. I've done the following steps:

1. Add new link to navigation
2. Css class example "menu-twitter"
3. Createad a mapp in child-theme folder "images"
4. Imported twitter.png
5. added following code in to style.css

   ```
   .menu-facebook {
       text-indent: -9999px;
       background-image: url(images/facebook.png) !important;
       background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
       margin-left: 100px !important; 
       width: 50px; 
   }

   .menu-facebook a:hoover {
       background: #f5f5f5 !important;
   }

   .menu-twitter {
       text-indent: -9999px;
       background-image: url(images/twitter.png) !important;
       background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
       margin-left: 100px !important; 
       width: 50px; 
   }

   .menu-instagram {
       text-indent: -9999px;
       background-image: url(images/instagram.png) !important;
       background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
       margin-left: 100px !important; 
       width: 50px; 
   }

   .menu-instagram a:hoover {
       background: #f5f5f5;
   }
   ```

Check out my site hkochd.suplife.se

I can't click on it and its positioned very wierd, what am I doing wrong?

*sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, links are anchored with the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>` tag. By your code you are indenting the anchor out of the page.

To avoid this you can apply the css to the `<a>` tag rather than the `<li>` tag.

Here is the modified code which will work

```
.menu-facebook a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url(images/facebook.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    margin-left: 100px !important; 
    width: 50px; 
}
.menu-facebook a:hover {
    background: #f5f5f5 !important;
}
.menu-twitter a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url(images/twitter.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    margin-left: 100px !important; 
    width: 50px; 
}
.menu-instagram a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url(images/instagram.png) !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    margin-left: 100px !important; 
    width: 50px; 
}
.menu-instagram a:hover {
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change you

```
.a:hoover {
```

to:

```
.a:hover {
```

To let those elements really change background color when hovering. Good luck with your website!

Comment: Typos should be mentioned in a comment.